# React website with gatsby template, blog posts are not stacking on the page in sequence, leaving gaps for some reason

Tags: html, css, reactjs, gatsby

I'm using a gatsby html5up template, and I'm attempting to fix an issue with the block posts not stacking properly.  Depending on the screen size, there are gaps because of the different lengths of text each post has.  I'm only guessing this is the reason, because I went through and made all the images the same size.  I've tried making each of the paragraphs the same height, but that didn't fix it.  What do I need to do to fix it so that it won't leave gaps?

My gallery code:

```
                <article className="6u 12u$(xsmall) work-item" key={i}>
                    <div className="articleDiv">
                        <a
                            className="image fit thumb"
                            href={obj.source}
                            onClick={e => {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                this.toggleLightbox(i);
                            }}
                        >
                            <img src={obj.thumbnail} />
                        </a>

                        <h3>{obj.caption}</h3>
                        <p>{obj.description}</p>
                    </div>
                </article>
```

Here's the html of the page for one of the posts:

```
<article class="6u 12u$(xsmall) work-item">
  <div class="articleDiv">
    <a class="image fit thumb" href="/static/15Fullsize-95788b0c2a3cd7f5b7be5197b162af0b.jpeg"><img src="/static/15Thumbnail-3f93874146f2072572920b9eb793a1cf.jpeg"></a>
    <h3>2005 Chevrolet Equinox LT AWD</h3>
    <p>Local vehicle with heated leather, moonroof, and lots more. Completely checked out, serviced, and inspected.  Only $4,995.  Gets around on the ice fantastic.</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

[image]

Here is a screenshot in developer to show the way the articles do not match up.

[image]

Comment: What do you see in the debugger on the empty slot?

Comment: There's no empty spot in the code, it just goes through all the articles.  I've edited the screenshot to show the order of the articles.

Comment: I've added a screenshot in developer, to show how the article in the #1 spot is coming down into blank spot, pushing the #3 to the right spot.

Comment: Have you tried setting a height for the article element?

Comment: Try experimenting on the margin and padding I guess.

Comment: I added a height of 16em to the workArticle, but then when I expand it into full screen, the pictures are pushed together vertically.

Answer (score 0):

This library for layout probably uses CSS `float` to build a grid, and you probably have to use clearfix somewhere.

If that is true, the space below the card appears because that card is higher than others (we can see that text has three lines while other cards have two lines).

Comment: I tried this:

 .work-item {
  margin: 0 0 _size(element-margin) 0;
  height: 20em;
But the pictures then went over the text as the pictures grew in size.

Comment: I'm afraid that you have to learn more CSS to fix that. You can set the height of the image with `height: 120px` and use `object-fit: cover;` to prevent them from squashing.